# Let $X_n$ and $U_n$ be independent, with $P(X_n = 0\, i.o.) = 1$ and $P(U_n = 0\, i.o.)$, show that $P(X_n = 0, U_{n+1} =0\, i.o.) = 1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_n$ and $U_n$ be independent, with $P(X_n = 0\ i.o.) = 1$ and $P(U_n = 0\ i.o.)$, show that $P(X_n = 0, U_{n+1} =0\, i.o.) = 1$.

Does this require additional assumptions to be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to the question before it was modified:

Let $X_n=1$ for $n$ odd, $0$ for $n$ even and $U_n=X_n$ for all $n$. Then $X_n=0$ implies $U_{n+1} \neq 0$ so the conclusion is false.

Comment: But $U_n$ and $X_n$ are independent here, how can we have $U_n = X_n$??

Comment: All the random variables I have defined are constant random variables. Any constant random variable is independent of itself!. @jackson5

Comment: Oh yes, of course! What are some minimal conditions I can put on X_n, U_n to make this true? What if U_n is Bernoulli(1/2)?

Comment: Ok, I will ask a new question